# Mockery not being able to count method calls on a Facade

Tags: testing, laravel, phpunit, mockery, laravel-5

There's a problem with a simple test which is not passing at all.
I have an action within the controller :

```
/**
 * @Get("/parse")
 * @param Dispatcher $dispatcher
 * @return string
 */
public function parse(){
    $xml_file = public_path()."/dummy.xml";
    //File::get($xml_file); Tried this as well
    $file = $this->file->get($xml_file);
    return $file;
}
```

And on the test I have a method like :

```
/**
 * A basic functional test example.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testBasicExample(){
        File::shouldReceive("get")->once();
        $this->call('GET', '/parse');
}
```

And on Laravel documentation, they say that each Facade can be Mocked directly, without instantiating it, but the test is never passing, I'm getting an exception :

```
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method get() from Mockery_0 should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times.
```

PS : I have Laravel 5 and on Test Class I have the tearDown method just in case you're wondering.

Comment: how do you inject your `$this->file` to the controller?

Comment: Through constructor, and Laravel does the rest by Depency Injector, but this does not work ever if I try with File::get()

Comment: certainly through constructor, I mean the code how you bind in your `ServiceProvider`.

Comment: It is a default Laravel Facade, with alias File, and it resolves Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem from IoC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution.

Instead of using the File, facade, I did inject the `FileSystem` depency through the constructor, and Mocked that on unit test, and passed the mocked object into **IoC Container**, and only that way worked, otherwise on Laravel 5, Mocking Facades is not working, `shouldReceive()` is not keeping count as we've been told by Laravel Docs.

Kind Regards